# BAT file to map to network drive without running as admin

Tags: windows, batch-file, drive

I'm trying to create a .bat file that will map to a network drive when it is clicked (it would be even better if it could connect automatically on login if connected to the network, otherwise do not connect)

What I have so far is:

```
net use P: "\\server\foldername\foldername"
```

Is there a way that I can create this so the users will not have to right click and run as an administrator? I would like it if they could just click the .bat file and it will map for them.

Comment: Are the computers on a domain?

Comment: Yes the computers are on a domain

Comment: That should work as-is. Why are you mentioning having to run it as an administrator?

Comment: I was having a problem where when I ran cygwin as admin, it wouldn't see the mapped drives.  So I would start cmd (RUN) with admin, then run the 'net use' as above, then start cygwin from the same shell.  Viola!   It worked, I could see the mapped drives in cygwin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just figured it out! What I did was I created the batch file like I had it originally:

```
net use P: "\\server\foldername\foldername"
```

I then saved it to the desktop and right clicked the properties and checked run as administrator. I then copied the file to C:\Users\"TheUser"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Where "TheUser" was the desired user I wanted to add it to.

Answer (score 29):

Save below in a `test.bat` and It'll work for you:

```
@echo off

net use Z: \\server\SharedFolderName password /user:domain\Username /persistent:yes
```

`/persistent:yes` flag will tell the computer to automatically reconnect this share on logon.  Otherwise, you need to run the script again during each boot to map the drive.

**For Example:**

```
net use Z: \\WindowsServer123\g$ P@ssw0rd /user:Mynetdomain\Sysadmin /persistent:yes
```

Comment: Would I need to save the file in the users log in files (if so do you know where this is located?) and when I add :user:domain\Username do I keep it like that or replace with our domain and username?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can put this `test.bat` file anywhere you want and YES you need to replace `domain\Username` with your respective domain and username.
I've added an example in answer for your reference.

Comment: That's the `password` for `Username` provided.It means the `password` which you use to login to remote system with given `Username`.

Comment: Ok, I tried it with the correct information; however, It doesn't map the drive. The only thing that works is what I had originally if I run the batch file as an admin

Comment: @Bhetzie This is an improvement, though: you get an admin to run this once, and it stays that way on future logins without intervention

Comment: I'm not sure why but this does not work for me, I created my batch file just like the example says to but it just doesn't work

Comment: I really don't like putting the password there in plain text. That's a huge security issue for me. Is there no other better way?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
net use z: /delete
cmdkey /add:servername /user:userserver /pass:userstrongpass

net use z: \\servername\userserver /savecred /persistent:yes
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\userserver_in_server.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "Z:\" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please  take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover,  open [Help] and read at least [answer]. Read more in [Down Vote “code only” answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers).

Comment: cmdkey command is cornerstone when dealing with shared folders

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a mapped network driver via 'net use' with admin privilege but failed, it does not show. And if I add it through UI, it disappeared after reboot, now I made that through powershell.
So, I think you can run powershell scripts from a .bat file, and the script is

`New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\Server01\Public"`

add `-persist` at the end, you will create a persisted mapped network drive

`New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\Server01\Scripts" -Persist`

for more details, refer [New-PSDrive - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 1):

> This .vbs code creates a .bat file with the current mapped network drives.
>   Then, just put the created file into the machine which you want to re-create the mappings and double-click it. It will try to create all mappings using the same drive letters (errors can occur if any letter is in use). This method also can be used as a backup of the current mappings.
>   Save the code bellow as a .vbs file (e.g. Mappings.vbs) and double-click it.

```
' ********** My Code **********
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

' ********** Get ComputerName
strComputer = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )

' ********** Get Domain 
sUserDomain = createobject("wscript.network").UserDomain

Set Connect = GetObject("winmgmts://"&strComputer)
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set oDrives = WshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
Set oPrinters = WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

' ********** Current Path
sCurrentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

' ********** Blank the report message
strMsg = ""

' ********** Set objects 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objWbem = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/default:StdRegProv")

' ********** Get UserName
sUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

' ********** Print user and computer
'strMsg = strMsg & "    User: " & sUser & VbCrLf
'strMsg = strMsg & "Computer: " & strComputer & VbCrLf & VbCrLf

strMsg = strMsg & "###  COPIED FROM " & strComputer & " ###" & VbCrLf& VbCrLf
strMsg = strMsg & "@echo off" & vbCrLf

For i = 0 to oDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
    strMsg = strMsg & "net use " & oDrives.Item(i) & " " & oDrives.Item(i+1) & " /user:" & sUserDomain & "\" & sUser & " /persistent:yes" & VbCrLf
Next
strMsg = strMsg & ":exit" & VbCrLf
strMsg = strMsg & "@pause" & VbCrLf

' ********** write the file to disk.
strDirectory = sCurrentPath 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
    ' Procede
Else
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
End if

' ********** Calculate date serial for filename **********
intMonth = month(now)
if intMonth < 10 then
    strThisMonth = "0" & intMonth
else
    strThisMonth = intMOnth
end if
intDay = Day(now)
if intDay < 10 then
    strThisDay = "0" & intDay
else
    strThisDay = intDay
end if
strFilenameDateSerial = year(now) & strThisMonth & strThisDay
    sFileName = strDirectory & "\" & strComputer & "_" & sUser & "_MappedDrives" & "_" & strFilenameDateSerial & ".bat"
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(sFileName,True) 
objFile.Write strMsg & vbCrLf

' ********** Ask to view file
strFinish = "End: A .bat was generated. " & VbCrLf & "Copy the generated file  (" & sFileName & ")  into the machine where you want to recreate the mappings and double-click it." & VbCrLf & VbCrLf 
MsgBox(strFinish)
```